# Cannot find module 'metro/src/lib/createWebsocketServer' react native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to run some app in react native,

when I run npx expo start

got this error:

```
>npx expo start
Starting project at C:\react\my-app
Error: Cannot find module 'metro/src/lib/createWebsocketServer'
Require stack:
- C:\react\my-app\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\server\metro\runServer-fork.js
- C:\react\my-app\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\server\metro\instantiateMetro.js
- C:\react\my-app\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\server\metro\MetroBundlerDevServer.js
- C:\react\my-app\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\server\DevServerManager.js
- C:\react\my-app\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\startAsync.js
- C:\react\my-app\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\index.js
- C:\react\my-app\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\bin\cli
- C:\react\my-app\node_modules\expo\bin\cli
```

I tried to fix this by `npx expo install`, but not working.
I am new in this react world and I am little lost.
I know that there was some upgrade before from npm to npx...
I tried also below commands but not working.

```
npm install
npx expo --version
npx expo install
npm install expo@latest
```

Can somebody share some info how to run / install dependencies / upgrade expo ?

Thank you

my expo version is:
npx expo --version
0.17.3

Answer (score 4):

fixed by:

```
npx expo install --fix
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks! I was looking fro this answer everywhere!!!